# Как получить ответ пользователя с помощью aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Вот так это можно сделать с помощью PyTelegramBotAPI

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["reg"]) 
def register(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет давай знакомиться,\nМеня зовут Юно, а тебя?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)
def reg_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Приятно познакомится, " + name + " \nА как ваша фамилия?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_surname)
def reg_surname(message):
    global surname
    surname = message.text
```

Или вот тот же код но на PyTelegramBotAPI

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["weather"])
def city(message):
    # We get the city about which you need to provide information.
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "О каком городе хотите увидеть информацию?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answer_cities)
def answer_cities(message):
    # Parse the json file.
    answer = requests.get("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=" + message.text + "&lang=ru&key=)
```

А как подобное можно реализовать с "aiogram"? Нужно получить название города который ввел пользователь.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands = ["weather"])
async def weather(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "город")
@dp.message_handler()
async def names(message: types.Message):    
    try:
        full = message.text
        print(full)
        answer = requests.get("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=" + full + "&lang=ru&key=")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 4):

Для этого есть [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html). Если оптимизировать пример по ссылке для Вашего случая, то выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```py
...

class WeatherForm(StatesGroup):
    city = State()  # Will be represented in storage as 'WeatherForm:city'


@dp.message_handler(commands='weather')
async def cmd_weather(message: types.Message):
    await WeatherForm.city.set()

    await message.reply("Введите Ваш город")


# You can use state '*' if you need to handle all states
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Allow user to cancel any action
    """
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return

    logging.info('Cancelling state %r', current_state)
    # Cancel state and inform user about it
    await state.finish()
    # And remove keyboard (just in case)
    await message.reply('Cancelled.', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


@dp.message_handler(state=WeatherForm.city)
async def process_city(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    city = message.text
    answer = requests.get(f"https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city={city}&lang=ru&key=")

    # Тут делайте всё, что Вам нужно

    await state.finish()
```